# android/opencv - load cascade files from app folder in NDK

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I'm writing an android app which does face detection in native code using OpenCV. Right now, I save `lbpcascade_frontalface.xml` in SD card and load it in NDK/C++ as below.

```
CascadeClassifier fc.load("absolute path to sd card/Downloads/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
```

However, I want to save it in the app package, may be in assets/res folder. Does anyone know how can I load it in C++/NDK? Rather how can i get the absolute path to this file if I need to save it somewhere in the app package itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opencv can't read from zip files directly.

so if you put the cascade into your apk, you'll have to load it and save it again to internal/external storage, like in the [facedetect sample](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/android/face-detection/src/org/opencv/samples/facedetect/FdActivity.java#L70)